# Typing keyof of a class property

Tags: typescript

If I have a class defined as:

```js
export class StepFunction {
  public stepNames: string[];
  private _startAt: string;

  public addStep(step: string) {
    this.stepNames.push(step);
  }
  public startAt(step: keyof typeof this._stepNames) { ... }

}
```

Sadly this isn't going to work as you can't reference types of a Class instance (it would appear). Is there any mechanism to achieve this goal with ES6 classes? What about outside classes?

---

Based on Aleksey's help I now see that referencing public instance methods is allowed for `keyof` but not `typeof keyof` which is really what I need to make this to work.

Attempting this give me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Syntax for accessing type members requires using square brackets (`step: keyof this['_stepNames']`). ** in order this to work, the member should be public.

Comment: Also it is not clear what are you trying to achieve from `keyof string[]` as it would be `number | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" ...`

Comment: I was attempting `keyof typeof` so that should limit to the strings in the array, right? That's great news about the instance referencing of public props. I wonder what the reason is for not allowing private.

Comment: it appears while the `keyof this['stepNames']` typing is allowed the typing i'm looking for `keyof typeof this['stepNames']` does not :(

Comment: You can't use keyof on a type, you must use it on an instance of a type.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis indeed that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Like I said, you can't do it a on type. `typeof this['stepNames']` is going to be a type and you can't call `keyof` on it. What you can do, is create a "dummy" instance of this type and call `keyof` on that. If you don't know what kind of type `this['stepNames']` is going to be, please share some more code and what you're trying to accomplish and we'll see what we can do with that.

Comment: the `stepNames` property will be built up over time with calls to `addStep()`; as it builds up other methods will be able to refer to a step which has been defined (but not other strings). I have updated the example to show the pattern a bit better.

Comment: _I was attempting keyof typeof so that should limit to the strings in the array, right?_ **No**

Comment: I was interested in what you'd said about a "dummy" instance; no idea how to do that but I'd love to gain from your experience

Comment: @ken Could you prepare a minimal reproducible example on stackblitz? Like I said, `keyof typeof something` just straight up isn't going to work, I'm sorry. If you could better explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you find a workaround that suits your needs. By reproducible, I mean include some example values and explain **how you would like the code to work**.

Comment: This question could use a [mcve] suitable for being dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).  You can make `startAt()` accept `this["stepNames"][number]`, but will end up being the same as `string`.  If you want `startAt()` to only accept *particular* strings, then you need to use [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) somewhere, and it will get more complicated.  But in any case, we need some example code that details what you need to work and not work. Good luck!

Comment: `typeof keyof` won't help you here. `stepNames` defined as  `string[]` - no way to get literal types from here. And of course typescript has no way to know which strings will be added to `stepNames` at runtime